# How can I send Image using Java webservice (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm new to java web services(restful), I need to serve image through java web service. From the client side I will call the web service in img src tag like `<img src="http://localhost:8080/test/inventory/getimage?imageName=1_1393842606.jpg"  />`. I'm placing my images in webapp on java side. I'm getting issue while reading the image from client side directly as mentioned above. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the image as a static resource, and include a link to it on any object that is supposed to contain it.

The fact that you're using a rest api doesn't mean that all your urls have to be managed by the same controller.

Comment: The images what we are referring are not static, user will upload them dynamically.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're using "localhost" in your image link, since it's an absolute URL user's browser tries to read the image from THEIR localhost, not YOURS. It should be enough to change it to

```
<img src="/test/inventory/getimage?imageName=1_1393842606.jpg"/>
```